# How to name an app with a different name for different languages (Unity3d, Android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

How can I name an app with a different name for different languages?

I am using Unity3d v. 5.2.3f1 Personal.

Answer (score 3):

If it doesn't already exist, create a folder \Assets\Plugins\Android\res\values-xx for each additional language you want to support. Substitute "xx" with the two letter language ( not country! ) code.

Also make one without a language code ( \Assets\Plugins\Android\res\values ) which will be the default one, if your device doesn't match any of the languages you created.

In each of those folders, create an xml file called strings.xml containing this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
     <string name="app_name">Hello World</string>
 </resources>
```

Resource- http://www.bitsofbas.com/blog/post/32/localizing-app-name-in-android

Comment: So you asked a question 2mins ago and answered it like 1 minute after ?

Comment: To be more accurate, I used answer "answer your own question" option at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

The folder name for localized strings should be like this scheme:

`<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country Code>]`

e.g. values-b+es/  … for spanish language

[Docs: Support different languages and cultures](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages)